Money & interest
In USA cheque cashing business is halal or haram? As far I know domestic money exchange is haram if international money transactions is permissible.
But check cashing business they quote that 2-5% or fixed rate permissible to operate business administrative cost but check cashing businesses is like a mini bank. I got business offers but my heart doesn’t respond it but huge profit margins yes it is also risky if someone scam u then bad but overall huge potential Allah knows better
Please clarify for me thanks

Your question is unclear, and there are many aspects. If you send an errand boy with some money to the grocery store that had given you credit, you would pay the boy for the errand. If he gets robbed, runs away with the money or just drops it, being too young for the task, you will take the risk. So fixed payment is appropriate. If you ask some bank or bank-like organization to do it, they will have to take the risk of losing your money, and will have to compensate. That risk is proportionally to the money in question.
